# What to retag [chrome] to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed that right now, we're using [chrome](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) for HTML5 games, much like we use [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash). I think that it's a little misleading, since almost all of them will work in FF4 or IE9 too. I understand that HTML5 was largely popularized by [Chrome Experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/), but I think that [html5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5), [webgl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webgl), or [canvas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canvas) would be better.

Comment: As the creator of the Chrome tag, I can say that it wasn't intended as an HTMl5 games tag, but rather to differentiate the html5 version of Angry Birds (http://chrome.angrybirds.com/) from other games in the Angry-Birds series, and not necessarily html5 games at large. Just something to note.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Yeah, I noticed, but if it's not going to be used like this, then it'd probably be best to just retag it to [chrome-angry-birds] (Which you might want to do anyway? I've never played any of the others, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: It's worth to note that some things are actually limited to Chrome. It's got the best implementation of HTML5 so far, lots of things, especially games, are still broken in FF4 and IE9.

Comment: Hmm, now that I think about it I support the `angry-birds-chrome` tag.  It's different enough that all the questions so far are unique to it, and it also works in Firefox. (I actually couldn't get it to work in Chrome at first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed all three occurrences to [html-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html-5); I haven't however created a synonym because the [chrome](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) tag may still be useful ("Quake Live doesn't load in Chrome (but it works in Firefox.)")

Comment: That's not true. Quake Live works in Chrome, and has for some time now.

Comment: @Arda ... it was an example.

Comment: I can't think of anything else, honestly.